# Compacting JSON-LD property w/ two different @types?

Tags: rdf, json-ld

I'm attempting to compact at JSON-LD document, see below (we're using URNs but the same issue occurs with URLs). I want `"org:example:property:schema;2"`to be compacted to `schema` in both of the usages below, **and** the nested objects of the schema property to also be compacted reasonably. Sadly, this seems so far impossible.

```
[
  {
    "@id": "org:example:ExampleThing",
    "org:example:property:contents;2": [
          {
        "@type": "org:example:class:Property;2",
        "org:example:property:schema;2": {
          "@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:integer;2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@id": "org:example:ExampleThing2",
    "org:example:property:contents;2": [
      {
        "@type": "org:example:class:Property;2",
        "org:example:property:schema;2": {
            "@type": "org:example:class:Enum;2",
            "org:example:property:valueSchema;2": {
                "@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:string;2"
            }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I would like to get out is the following:

```
[
    {
      "@id": "org:example:ExampleThing",
      "contents": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "schema": {
          "@id": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "org:example:ExampleThing2",
      "contents": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "schema": {
          "@type": "Enum",
          "valueSchema": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

The closest I've gotten is the following context. In it, however, `org:example:instance:Schema:integer;2` is **not** compacted as required. Adding `"@type": "@vocab"` to the `schema` definition resolves this for `ExampleThing`, but then the `schema` term does not match the usage of the property in `ExampleThing2`, so it is not compacted there instead.

```
{
  "Property": { "@id": "org:example:class:Property;2" },
  "Enum": { "@id": "org:example:class:Enum;2" },
  "contents": { "@id": "org:example:property:contents;2" },
  "schema": { "@id": "org:example:property:schema;2" },
  "valueSchema": {
      "@id": "org:example:property:valueSchema;2",
      "@type": "@vocab"
  },
  "integer": { "@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:integer;2" },
  "string": { "@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:string;2" }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is pretty close to what you want. You can check out the [playground link](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3AExampleThing%22%2C%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3Acontents%3B2%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aclass%3AProperty%3B2%22%2C%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3Aschema%3B2%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Ainstance%3ASchema%3Ainteger%3B2%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3AExampleThing2%22%2C%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3Acontents%3B2%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aclass%3AProperty%3B2%22%2C%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3Aschema%3B2%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aclass%3AEnum%3B2%22%2C%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3AvalueSchema%3B2%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Ainstance%3ASchema%3Astring%3B2%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22Property%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aclass%3AProperty%3B2%22%7D%2C%22Enum%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aclass%3AEnum%3B2%22%7D%2C%22contents%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3Acontents%3B2%22%7D%2C%22schema%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3Aschema%3B2%22%7D%2C%22valueSchema%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Aproperty%3AvalueSchema%3B2%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%7D%2C%22integer%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Ainstance%3ASchema%3Ainteger%3B2%22%7D%2C%22string%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22org%3Aexample%3Ainstance%3ASchema%3Astring%3B2%22%7D%7D%7D) here.

The main issue is that the `"org:example:instance:Schema:integer;2"` `@id` value can't be compacted any further, as values of `@id` are treated as IRIs relative to the document location, or `@base`. You could add an `@base` declaration to the context, which could get you somewhat closer. You could do better using scoped contexts, and use a different `@base` in the context scoped under either `Property` or `schema`.

Without doing that, this is what the compaction result looks like:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "Property": {"@id": "org:example:class:Property;2"},
    "Enum": {"@id": "org:example:class:Enum;2"},
    "contents": {"@id": "org:example:property:contents;2"},
    "schema": {"@id": "org:example:property:schema;2"},
    "valueSchema": {
      "@id": "org:example:property:valueSchema;2",
      "@type": "@vocab"
    },
    "integer": {"@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:integer;2"},
    "string": {"@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:string;2"}
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "org:example:ExampleThing",
      "contents": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "schema": {
          "@id": "org:example:instance:Schema:integer;2"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "@id": "org:example:ExampleThing2",
      "contents": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "schema": {
          "@type": "Enum",
          "valueSchema": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can read more in the [Shortening IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#shortening-iris) section of the spec.

Comment: Thank you! It is unfortunate that I cannot achieve what I'd like to here, but I guess I'll have to make do.